# Explanation of this code: Determining if a point is on which side of a line

Tags: python, numpy, vector, linear-algebra, perceptron

Source: http://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/machine-learning-classics-the-perceptron/

"The general equation of a line given two points in it, `(x1,y2)` and `(x2,y2)`, is `A + Bx + Cy = 0` where `A`, `B`, `C` can be written in terms of the two points. Defining a vector `V = (A, B, C)`, any point `(x,y)` belongs to the line if `V'x = 0`, where `x = (1,x,y)`. Points for which the dot product is positive fall on one side of the line, negatives fall on the other."

I don't quite understand how it works. Also, this line in particular:

```
self.V = np.array([xB*yA-xA*yB, yB-yA, xA-xB])
```

Why is `Bx` determined by `yb-ya`?

For what its worth, I'm learning Linear Algebra, so I'm quite familiar with the mathematical concept (I realize it is meant to be a normal), but how it is done escapes me.

Comment: I don't see Bx anywhere in the source you referenced, so I can't quite follow your specificy question about how it's determined.

Comment: Are you asking how the math works, or how its translated into code?

Comment: Bx as in, A + Bx + Cy = 0. Not to worry though, someone provided the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why is B determined by yb - ya? (or rather y2 - y1 for our example)

The text assumes the line equation to be: `A + B*x + C*y = 0`

Let's say we have two points from that line, `P1(x1, y1)` and `P2(x2, y2)`

Using the [two-points form of the line equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form), you will get `y - y1 = [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)] * (x - x1)` (based on `P1`and `P2`)

The same equation, can be developed into `[(x2 -x1)*y1 + (y1 - y2)*x1] + (y2 - y1) * x + (x1 - x2) * y  = 0`

Looking at `A + B*x + C*y = 0`, you see that:

- `A`, is `[(x2 -x1)*y1 + (y1 - y2)*x1] = x2*y1 - y2*x1`
- `B`, the coefficient of `x` is `(y2 - y1)`
- `C`, the coefficient of `y` is `(x1 - x2)`

hence the value `np.array([A, B, C])` in the source code appears as `np.array([xB*yA - xA*yB, yB - yA, xA - xB])`